# Page not found (404) No cart matches the given query

Tags: python, get, http-status-code-404

The error is raised :

> Page not found (404)  No cart matches the given query.
> Request Method:   GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/change_quan?cid=1&quantity=2
> Raised by:    myapp.views.change_quan

when i am trying to save quantity value in database
i tried but this error raised always

my views.py

```
def productcart(request):
context = {}
items = cart.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id,status=False)
context["items"] = items
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method=="POST":
       pid = request.POST["pid"]
       qty = request.POST["qty"]
       img = request.POST["img"]
       dis_price = request.POST["dis_price"]
       is_exist = cart.objects.filter(product__id=pid,user__id=request.user.id,status=False)
       if len(is_exist)>0:
           context["msg"] = "item already exist in cart"
           context["cls"] = "alert alert-warning"
       else:
          product = get_object_or_404(Product,id=pid)
          usr = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.user.id)
          c = cart(user=usr,product=product,quantity=qty,image=img,total_price=dis_price)
          c.save()
          context["msg"] = "{} Added in cart".format(product.name)
          context["cls"] = "alert alert-success"
          
else:
    context["status"] = "Please login first to add products to cart"
return render(request,'E-commerce-cart.html',context)


def get_cart_data(request):
items = cart.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id,status=False)
sale,total,quantity=0,0,0
for i in items:
    sale+=i.product.discount
    total+=i.product.price
    quantity+=i.quantity

res={
    "total":total,"offer":sale,"quan":quantity
}
return JsonResponse(res)

def change_quan(request):
        qty = request.GET["quantity"]
        cid = request.GET["cid"]
        print(request.GET)
        cart_obj = get_object_or_404(cart,id=cid)
        cart_obj.quantity = qty
        cart_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse(1)
```

my urls.py

```
    """emarket URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from os import name
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('shop/',views.shop,name='shop'),
    path('login/',views.create_user,name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('cart/',views.productcart,name='cart'),
    path('checkout/',views.checkout,name='checkout'),
    path('product_detail/',views.product_detail,name='prodct-detail'),
    path('find_us/',views.find_us,name='find'),
    path('blog/',views.blog,name='blog'),
    path('base/',views.base),
    path('api/categories',views.all_categories,name="all_categories"),
    path('api/brand',views.brand,name="brand"),
    path('api/products',views.product_filter_api,name="product_filter_api"),
    path('user_check/',views.check_user,name="check_user"),
    path('filter_product/',views.filter_product,name="filter_product"),
    path('add_to_favourite/',views.add_to_favourite,name="add_to_favourite"),
    path('all_favourites/',views.all_favourites,name="all_favourites"),
    path('forgotpass',views.forgotpass,name="forgotpass"),
    path('resetpass',views.resetpass,name="resetpass"),
    path('get_cart_data',views.get_cart_data,name="get_cart_data"),
    path('change_quan',views.change_quan,name='change_quan'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py

```
class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default=False)
    total_price=models.FloatField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my html code

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<style>
        .k{height: 1px;background-color: rgb(211, 207, 207);}
    .s{color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;}
    .cncl_icn{
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .a:hover{
        background-color:rgba(152, 209, 255, 0.705);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);box-shadow:0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(204, 201, 201, 0.5) ;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:680px){
        .b{opacity: 0;}
        /* .v{position: absolute;top: 5px;} */
        .s{font-size: 15px;}
        }
    @media screen and (min-width:1024px){
        .s{font-size: 20px;}
        }
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% if user.is_superuser %}
<div class="container-fluid "></div>
    <h1 class="jumbotron my-5" >you are not Allowed here</h1>
{% else %}
     {% if status %}
       <h1 class="jumbotron my-5">{{status}}</h1>
     {% else %}
     {% if msg %}
     <div class="{{cls}}">{{msg}}</div>
     {% endif %}
       <div class="row v " style="margin-right: 0%;">
        <div class="col-lg-7"  >
            <div class="row text-center p-3  b" style="background-color: rgba(2, 184, 184, 0.863); background-attachment: fixed;">
                <div class="col-md-3 "> <h3 class="s">Product</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 "><h3 class="s">Price</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 "><h3 class="s">Qantity</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 "><h3 class="s">Total</h3></div>
            </div>
            {% for i in items %}
             <div class="row a border-bottom"  id="col{{i.product.id}}">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center " >
                   <i class="far fa-times-circle cncl_icn" id="cross{{i.product.id}}" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
                    <img class="mt-4" src="/media/{{i.image}}" alt="check ur internet!" height="150px">
                    <a href="/product_detail/?id={{i.product.id}}" style="text-decoration: none;"><h4 class="ml-5" style="color: black;">{{i.product.name}}</h4></a>
                    <p class="ml-5">Size:{{i.product.size}} , color:{{i.product.color}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center mt-5">
                    {%if i.total_price < i.product.price%}
                    <del style="font-weight: bold; color: grey;" >${{i.product.price}}</del> $<p class="d-inline" style="font-weight: bold;" id="price{{i.product.id}}">{{i.total_price}}</p>
                    {% else %}
                    $<p class="d-inline" style="font-weight: bold;" id="price{{i.product.id}}">{{i.product.price}}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn ">
                                <button id="down" class="btn btn-default" onclick="change_quan('{{i.product.id}}','minus')"  style="font-size: 25px;background: none;border: none;font-weight: bold;">-</button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="number" id="cart{{i.product.id}}"  class="form-control text-center pt-3" value="{{i.quantity}}" style="width: 30px;border: none;font-weight: bold;background: none;">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="up" class="btn btn-default" onclick="change_quan('{{i.product.id}}','plus')" style="font-size: 25px;background: none;border: none;font-weight: bold;">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mt-5 text-center">
                    {%if i.total_price < i.product.price %}
                    $<p class="d-inline" style="font-weight: bold;" id="total{{i.product.id}}">{{i.total_price}}</p>
                    {% else %}
                    $<p class="d-inline" style="font-weight: bold;" id="total{{i.product.id}}">{{i.product.price}}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $("#cross{{i.product.id}}").hover(function() {
                        $("#cross{{i.product.id}}").toggleClass("fas fa-times-circle").toggleClass("far fa-times-circle")
                    })
                    // to remove product from cart
                    $("#cross{{i.product.id}}").confirm({
                        title: 'Confirm',
                        content: 'Are you sure to remove this product from cart',
                        theme: 'modern',
                        buttons:{

                            confirm: function() {
                            $('#col{{i.product.id}}').remove()
                        },
                            cancel: function (){}
                        }
                       
                    })
                })
            </script>  
            {% endfor %}
        </div> 
        <script>
            function grandTotal(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{% url 'get_cart_data' %}",
                    type:'get',
                    success:function(data){
                        p = Math.round((data.offer/data.total)*100,2)
                        $('.item_total').html("&dollar;"+data.total)
                        $('#offer').html("&dollar;"+data.offer)
                        $('#per').html("("+p+"%)")
                        $('#quantity').html(data.quan)
                        c = (data.total)-(data.offer)
                        $('#grand_Total').html("&dollar;"+c)
                    }
                })
            }
            grandTotal()

            function change_quan(id,action){
                let old = $("#cart"+id).val();
                quan = 0
                if(action=="plus"){
                    quan+=parseInt(old)+1
                    $('#total'+id).text( parseFloat($('#total'+id).text()) +  parseFloat($('#price'+id).text()))
                }
                else{
                    quan+=parseInt(old)-1
                    $('#total'+id).text( parseFloat($('#total'+id).text()) -  parseFloat($('#price'+id).text()))
                }
                $("#cart"+id).val(quan);

                $.ajax({
                    url:"{% url 'change_quan' %}",
                    type:"get",
                    data:{cid:id,quantity:quan},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data)
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
         <div class="col-md-5 text-center py-5" style="background-color: rgba(255, 176, 218, 0.397);">
<div id="cartt"></div>
            <div class="row">
                    <img src="/static/Images/estore1.png" alt="" height="300px" style="margin: auto;">
            </div>
            <div class="pb-3 " style="font-size:30px;font-weight: bold;">--------------------</div>
            <h4 class="pt-3" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 3px;text-transform: uppercase;">Total: <span style="font-size: 28px;" class="item_total"></span></h4>
            <h4 class="pt-1" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 3px;text-transform: uppercase;">Quantity: <span style="font-size: 28px;" id="quantity"></span><span style="text-transform: none;"> Items</span></h4>
            <h4 class="pt-1" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 3px;text-transform: uppercase;">You Saved: <span style="font-size: 28px;" id="offer"></span><span class='text-success'style="font-size: 20px;" id="per"></span></h4>
            <h4 class="py-1" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 3px;text-transform: uppercase;">Grand Total: <del style="font-size: 25px; color:grey;" class="item_total"></del><span style="font-size: 28px;" id="grand_Total"></span></h4>
            <h4 class="pt-3">Shipping charges will calculated at checkout</h4>
            <form class="pt-3" action=""  >
                <!-- <input type="text"  placeholder="Coupon code.." name="cod" class="mt-3 text-center" style="letter-spacing: 2px;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 25px;width: 250px;height: 47px;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);border:2px solid thistle;" >
               <input type="submit" class="mt-3" value="Apply Code"name="acd" style="letter-spacing: 2px;font-size: 25px;border-radius: 25px;border: none;width: 250px;height: 45px;background-color: rgb(161, 158, 158);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" > -->
                <input  type="submit" value="CHECKOUT" name="che" class="mt-5" style="letter-spacing: 2px;font-size: 25px;border-radius: 25px;border: none;width: 250px;height: 45px;background-color: black;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" >
            </form>
        </div> 
     </div>
     {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript? Anyway, after `cart_obj = get_object_or_404(cart,id=cid)` try logging `cart_obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if data does not exist 'get_object_or_404' will throw 404 error, As per your request You are trying to retrieve data with primary key 1, but data is not available
That’s why you get this error. so please check you table or try with other pk value

```
def change_quan(request):
    qty = request.GET["quantity"]
    cid = request.GET["cid"]
    print(request.GET)
    cart_obj = get_object_or_404(cart,id=cid)  # please check this cid value 
    cart_obj.quantity = qty
    cart_obj.save()
    return HttpResponse(1)
```

Comment: thanks for helping. The error is solved. I tried product__id=cid and it works

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` is not the correct choice here. Since object with `id=cid` was not found in database, 404 error was raised. This is the expected behaviour of `get_object_or_404`.

Did you mean to use `get_or_create` object incase the object that is trying to be fetched from database is not found?

Comment: thanks for helping. The error is solved.  I tried product__id=cid and it works